# Why is my index on the join keys not used in a very simple hash join case?

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, execution-plan

I have two tables:

```
create table animal
(
    aid integer,
    cid integer,
    aname varchar(255) default NULL::character varying,
    species text
);

create table daily_feeds
(
    aid integer,
    zid integer,
    shift integer,
    menu integer
);
```

and a query:

```
SELECT
aname,
shift
FROM animal
NATURAL JOIN daily_feeds
WHERE menu = 1;
```

The table animal contains around 40000 row, the table daily_feeds contains around 80000 row, 2 for each animal.

I thought that adding an index on the columns used for the join *animal.aid* and *daily_feeds.aid* could result in a different execution plan and improved performances.

```
create index aaid on animal (aid);

create index daid on daily_feeds using btree (aid);
```

This doesn't happen. Why is that?

Obviously this is a very simple and academic example that I'm trying to use to learn more about database query optimization.

EDIT:

Added execution plan when no indexes are present:

```
Hash Join  (cost=1439.24..2488.23 rows=499 width=10) (actual time=11.701..55.260 rows=487 loops=1)
    Hash Cond: (animal.aid = daily_feeds.aid)
    ->  Seq Scan on animal  (cost=0.00..694.00 rows=40000 width=10) (actual  time=0.007..20.775 rows=40000 loops=1)
    ->  Hash  (cost=1433.00..1433.00 rows=499 width=8) (actual time=11.590..11.590 rows=487 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 28kB
        ->  Seq Scan on daily_feeds  (cost=0.00..1433.00 rows=499 width=8) (actual time=0.011..11.218 rows=487 loops=1)
            Filter: (menu = 1)
            Rows Removed by Filter: 79513
Planning time: 0.124 ms
Execution time: 55.521 ms
```

EDIT2: another question here:

Since I use two indexes I can also make them clustered indexes, physically ordering the table by the *aid* attribute.

```
cluster animal using aaid;
cluster daily_feeds using daid;
```

If I do that the Execution Plan doesn't change again. Isn't a Merge Join a more effective join strategy if both tables are sorted by the key column?

I'm not really sure about the behavior of Postgres here.

Comment: You may wish to try "select aid from a nat join d where 1=1" as a starting point so that only fields within the index are required.

Comment: @heapOverflow you may have to break it up `vacuum full analyze aaid;` `vaccum full analyze daid` it removes dead tuples in the table by rewriting it and the index and it refreshes the planners statistics

Comment: Unable to reproduce your explain output: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c44a86617ea9ffe0e7559eda96a08fb1

Can you create or modify the DB Fiddle above and display your explain plan?

Edit: didn't realize alt-tab submits :)

Comment: What about this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c70f0/1 . Actually I found a very weird thing I didn't know it was possible, in some cases the execution plan changed (from using a Merge Join to a Hash Join) after around 10 executions.

Comment: @crokusek: you main select aid instead of aname?

Answer (score 6):

Providing information on the actual query plan used would help.

Speaking in general, the DB engine would have to use the two indexes to identify rows in both tables that have matching `aid` values; then, *look up* all the actual rows in the `daily_feeds` table to see if `menu` is 1, and then look up the rows in `animal` to get the `aname` values.

If there was a large number of rows to be returned, and if those are your complete tables, then it may well have decided it would be faster to simply load the tables in the first place, and scan them to find the matching rows and do the `menu` check (at which point `aname` is already there and available).

---

Let me note here that I'm most familiar with the way SQL Server uses indexes. It's possible that some of the following may not directly apply to PostgreSQL. However, most of the basics seem to match up, and I'm not going to delve into specifics enough to be likely to go too far wrong.

The optimizer has three ways to find rows in `daily_feeds`. It can simply look through the entire table; it can use the `aid` index to seek to a particular value or range of values of `aid`, then use the index information to go to the correct pages in the table to get the rows; or, it can treat the index as if it was a table, and scan that (possibly looking up the rows in the full table, if all the data it needs isn't in the index).

There are many consideration an optimizer must make in figuring out how to get the data it needs. One factor is the amount of pages it might have to load to get the data. Loading pages form disk is one of the most time-consuming tasks for a database. So, if it can limit the number of pages it may need, then that should speed up the query.

For this query, we need to find two columns in `animal` (`aid` and `aname`), and three in `daily_feeds` (`aid`, `menu`, `shift`).

It has two ways to identify the rows it's interested in: rows where an `aid` in `animal` matches an `aid` in `daily_feeds`, and rows where `menu` is 1. I'll guess that statistics would indicate (certainly a foreign key relationship would, if it actually existed) that all or almost all rows would be returned form both tables based on the `aid` = `aid` check. That doesn't do a good job of reducing the number of rows we're looking for. However, `menu` = 1 knocks out a lot of rows. Since `menu` isn't in an index, we have to go to the table to filter it by that.

Once we've got the `daily_feeds` rows we want, we need to find the matching rows in `animal` to pick up `aname`. We can expect to be looking for around 500 rows, and must assume (worst case) they're evenly distributed through the `animal` data. I'm make another assumption here; that (even with a `text` column) the rows in the `animal` table aren't terribly wide. If the basic table is stored in 500 pages (ignoring the `text` data; it may be stored off-row, but we don't need it for this query), then the odds are that all the pages will have to be loaded to get the rows we need.

Now, there are two paths to proceed:

- Use the `aaid` index on `animal` to find the 500 `aid` values we're looking for; then, using the index, go to the pages where the data lives and find them in each page.
- Load the `animal` table directly, and scan it for the 500 `aid` values we're looking for directly.

The optimizer decided to use option 2. Looking at it from this perspective, that doesn't necessarily seem that odd.

Note: the engine may be deciding this entire plan *before it takes its first step*. This can lead to bad plans (if, for instance, it turned out that `menu` = 1 only brought back 5 rows, then using the index might be faster) on occasion. SQL Server can maintain statistics on columns that help it determine cardinality (how well a known value for column X will limit the target rows), to help it make these decisions. PostgreSQL has some sort of statistic facility as well - not sure if it's directly comparable or not.

Answer (score 2):

What is the distribution of menu? I.e. what percentage of rows have menu = 1? Including menu in the index may be beneficial. I.e:

```
create index daid on daily_feeds using btree (aid, menu);
```

or the other way around.

I assume this is just a small example, otherwise having tables where nothing is mandatory is a bad idea. Also make sure that you have proper keys defined for the tables, I don't now postgresql that well but I assume this will help the optimizer make good decisions on the execution plan (beside the obvious reasons for consistency).

I would also like to warn against using natural joins, it may seem like a good idea at first but sooner or later you will have two columns with the same name that is completely unrelated (say submit_time as an example).

As a side note I wish there were some kind of referential join that used existing foreign keys to determine which columns to use in the join. Unfortunate I don't think there are any DBMS:s that implements this.

Comment: There are 160 menus, distributed roughly uniformly. And you are right that an index on menu speeds up the query. But here my goal is not really to optimize the query (it's a fake environment) but to understand the indexes and I still I can't understand why the indexes on the keys are not used when, apparently, it would make sense.

Comment: In a nested loop join you would still have to lookup menu, so my guess is that the optimizer considers it cheaper to do a hash join. I understand that this is just an experiment, but I still think you should add "not null" constraint and primary keys (and a foreign key if `daily_feeds` is a child table of `animal`)

Comment: Any particular reason you think it's important in this case? From the point of view of the performance, i just made a test and there is no difference.